# Saving big xlsx files pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, save

I am trying to connect 20 excel files into one and save it to excel. 
It should be in one sheet. My idea so far was to read all the files into dataframes, concat them and save to excel. After concatening I have a dataframe which shape is (1245226, 20), after saving file the size in excel is (1048576, 20) and its size on disk is 61 MB. Below I am posting the methods I tested to save the file:

```
>> df.shape
(1245226, 20)
```

Method 1 - getting (1048576, 20) instead of (1245226, 20)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path)
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.close()
```

Method 2 - not being able to save file, because of lack of memory (16 gb RAM)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.close()
```

Method 3 - getting (1048576, 20) instead of (1245226, 20)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, enigne='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.close()
```

Any ideas how to save it? Maybe there is a method to append data straightly to excel file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66743446/9067615

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't.

The maximum dimensions of an Excel spreadsheet are 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: I see. Thank you for your quick answer.